# Can you have a calculated boolean property in Swift?

Tags: swift, design-patterns, boolean

I'm trying to model possession in a sport where one team always has the ball: `homeTeamHasPossession` or `awayTeamHasPossession`. With only two options a boolean seems to make sense but it feels clunky to write `!homeTeamHasPossession` everywhere when what I really mean is `awayTeamHasPossession`.

One simple answer is to make `awayTeamHasPossession` a function instead of a variable but it would be nice to have the option to toggle either of them:

```
var homeTeamHasPossession:Bool = true
func awayTeamHasPossession() -> Bool {
    return !homeTeamHasPossession
}

print("A: " + homeTeamHasPossession.description)    // A: true
print ("B: " + awayTeamHasPossession().description) // B: false

homeTeamHasPossession.toggle()

print("A: " + homeTeamHasPossession.description)    // A: false
print ("B: " + awayTeamHasPossession().description) // B: true

awayTeamHasPossession().toggle() // I can't do this
```

Am I missing something obvious? Is there another pattern I could use here? Am I just being fussy about `!homeTeamHasPossession` not being expressive enough?

Comment: It's not very clear what your goal is. Can you update your question with a real example of what you are doing. Show your use of `a` and `!a` and make it clear how `!a` isn't what you want.

Comment: "With only two options a boolean seems to make sense" Depends. In a lot of cases, a 2 case enum makes more sense.

Comment: We'll need more detail into exactly what your use case is, so that we can better suggest an answer

Comment: Additional info regarding intent provided... I did consider enums but a) I'm not really sure how to use them here and b) I like the idea of being able to use the booleans in if statements and ternary conditions e.g. `if homeTeamHasPossession {` or `awayTeamHasPossession ? defensiveInfringement : offensiveInfringement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do `toggle` because `awayTeamHasPossession` isn't even a property, let alone a mutable one.

To fix it, just write a mutable computed property!

```
var awayTeamHasPossession: Bool {
    get { return !homeTeamHasPossession }
    set { homeTeamHasPossesion = !newValue }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
awayTeamHasPossession.toggle()
```

Actually, toggling `awayTramHasPossession` is the same as toggling `homeTeamHasPossession` isn't it? So another way to fix this would be to write `homeTeamHasPossession.toggle()`

Comment: Computed property, that's exactly what I was after! I feel like I was so close with my "calculated property" description... perhaps my Google-fu is waning